# How to reference dynamic variables using LOOP in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
clear screen;
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
ID_1 number;
ID_2 number;
filter1 varchar2(100);
filter2 varchar2(100);

BEGIN
ID_1 := 100;
ID_2 := 101;

FOR i in 1..2
LOOP
        IF ID_(i) is not null THEN
        SELECT STATE INTO filter(i)
        FROM dashboard
        WHERE id=ID_(i);
        END IF;
    
        dbms_output.put_line(filter(i));

END LOOP;

END;
```

I want to dynamically create values and then print variables using 'i' from the loop. In this example i am taking only 2 values but i can get up to 10 in total.
Obviously this code doesn't work. How can i do it?

Comment: Use collections https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE
type t_ids is table of dashboard.id%type index by pls_integer;
type t_filters is table of dashboard.state%type index by pls_integer;
v_IDs t_ids;
v_filters t_filters;

BEGIN
V_IDs(1):= 100;
V_IDs(2):= 101;

FOR i in 1..2
LOOP
        IF v_ids(i) is not null THEN
        SELECT d.STATE INTO v_filters(i)
        FROM dashboard d
        WHERE d.id=v_ids(i);
        END IF;
    
        dbms_output.put_line(v_filters(i));

END LOOP;

END;
```

PS. Excuse me for possible typos. Typed on my phone.

Comment: Thank you Sayan. The ID_1 and ID_2 i am referencing are hard coded for the purpose of the example. I will be getting these as auto generated by the system. So how do i make v_IDs for that? So if the user select 3 then i will have 3 ids auto generated which i will pass in the query below. How can i do it in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic things require dynamic SQL. *Everything* should be "dynamic" here (if I correctly understood what you are asking).

Here's an example based on Scott's `DEPT` table; I'll fetch department name for departments 10 (`id_1`) and 20 (`id_2`).

```
SQL> select * from dept order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK             --> this
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS               --> and this
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 2 loop
  3      execute immediate
  4        'declare ' ||
  5        '  id_1    number := 10; ' ||
  6        '  id_2    number := 20; ' ||
  7        '  filter1 varchar2(10); ' ||
  8        '  filter2 varchar2(10); ' ||
  9        'begin' ||
 10        '  select dname into filter' || i ||
 11        '  from dept '               ||
 12        '  where deptno = id_'  || i ||';' ||
 13        '  dbms_output.put_line(filter' || i ||');' ||
 14        'end;';
 15    end loop;
 16  end;
 17  /
ACCOUNTING                                      --> here they
RESEARCH                                        --> are

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```